# Generate all combination of dictionaries containing ranges

Tags: dictionary, range, julia

In julia I have a dictionary that can contains other dictionaries, lists of strings/numbers, lists of dictionaries, strings/numbers, and ranges.

I need a list containing all the possible combination of dictionaries for every range (like StepRange, FloatRange, UnitRange) it's contained in it.

Example:

```
Dict{}("A" => Dict{}("B" => 1:1:3, "C" => 2), "B" => [Dict{}( "S" => 1:1.1:2.1)])
```

=>

```
[
Dict{}("A" => Dict{}("B" => 1, "C" => 2), "B" => [Dict{}( "S" => 1.1)]),
Dict{}("A" => Dict{}("B" => 2, "C" => 2), "B" => [Dict{}( "S" => 1.1)]),
Dict{}("A" => Dict{}("B" => 3, "C" => 2), "B" => [Dict{}( "S" => 1.1)]),
Dict{}("A" => Dict{}("B" => 1, "C" => 2), "B" => [Dict{}( "S" => 2.1)]),
Dict{}("A" => Dict{}("B" => 2, "C" => 2), "B" => [Dict{}( "S" => 2.1)]),
Dict{}("A" => Dict{}("B" => 3, "C" => 2), "B" => [Dict{}( "S" => 2.1)])
]
```

Right now, I'm overloading a recursive function like this, but have no idea on how to continue.

```
function iterate(generic, nets::Array)
    return (generic, false)
end

function iterate(range::Union{StepRange,FloatRange,UnitRange}, nets::Array)
    return (collect(range), true)
end

function iterate(array::Array, nets::Array)
    for (n, v) in enumerate(array)
        res = iterate(v, nets)
        if res[2]
            ## We found a range! Return it
            return res
        end
    end
    return (array, false)
end

function iterate(dict::Dict, nets::Array)
    for (k, v) in dict
        res = iterate(v, nets)
        if res[2]
            return (dict, true)
        end
    end
    return (dict, false)
end
```

(I have already done this in python, but working on piece of text, using regex to find custom-defined ranges (like "[1,2,0.1]") and after generating the text code parsing it.)

Comment: In the example, `"B"=>1:1:3` while the output lists only `"B"=>1` and `"B"=2` and not `"B"=>3`. Is this a bug/typo? (since `collect(1:1:3)==[1,2,3]`)

Comment: Fixed, sorry.  I was hating stackoverflow text editor and wanted to get out of it as soon as possible :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet reproduces the output in the example, and it could serve as a basis for other variants which treat the recursion differently (there are many options, as I noticed when trying this out). It using `Iterators.jl` which is installed with `Pkg.add("Iterators")`.

```
using Iterators

function findranges{K}(sd::Dict{K})
  ranges = Vector{Vector}()
  for v in values(sd)
    if isa(v,Range)
      push!(ranges,collect(v))
    elseif isa(v,Dict)
      push!(ranges,recdictcollect(v))
    elseif isa(v,Vector)
      push!(ranges,map(x->vcat(x...),collect(product(map(recdictcollect,v)...))))
    end
  end
  ranges
end

function recdictcollect{K}(sd::Dict{K})
  ranges = findranges(sd)
  if length(ranges)==0
    cases = [()]
  else
    cases = product(ranges...) |> collect
  end
  outv = Vector{Dict{K,Any}}()
  for c in cases
    newd = Dict{K,Any}()
    i = 1
    for (k,v) in sd
      if any([isa(v,t) for t in [Range,Dict,Vector]])
        newd[k] = c[i]
        i += 1
      else
        newd[k] = v
      end
    end
    push!(outv,newd)
  end
  return outv
end
```

And the example:

```
julia> example = Dict{}("A" => Dict{}("B" => 1:1:3, "C" => 2), "B" => [Dict{}( "S" => 1:1.1:2.1)])
Dict{ASCIIString,Any} with 2 entries:
  "B" => [Dict("S"=>1.0:1.1:2.1)]
  "A" => Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("B"=>1:1:3,"C"=>2)

julia> recdictcollect(example)
6-element Array{Dict{ASCIIString,Any},1}:
 Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("B"=>[Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("S"=>1.0)],"A"=>Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("B"=>1,"C"=>2))
 Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("B"=>[Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("S"=>2.1)],"A"=>Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("B"=>1,"C"=>2))
 Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("B"=>[Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("S"=>1.0)],"A"=>Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("B"=>2,"C"=>2))
 Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("B"=>[Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("S"=>2.1)],"A"=>Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("B"=>2,"C"=>2))
 Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("B"=>[Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("S"=>1.0)],"A"=>Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("B"=>3,"C"=>2))
 Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("B"=>[Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("S"=>2.1)],"A"=>Dict{ASCIIString,Any}("B"=>3,"C"=>2))
```

Comment: On the real world example I had to add: recdictcollect(sd::Int) = sd, but this definitely does the trick!
Thanks